# Anonymise SQLite database?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Problem: I have a table with first name, surname, and gender columns. I need to partially anonymise the database, by replacing all the names in this table with arbitrary made-up names. I also have a spreadsheet with lots of gender-specific arbitrary names.

Given this, how do I iterate through the rows of this table, and replace each name in turn with a name from the spreadsheet?

I can do this in C fairly trivially, but it's a days work - export the spreadsheet as CSV, and then iterate through the rows of the table, updating each name with the next one from the CSV file. However, I can't help feeling that there's a much simpler way to do this by turning the CSV name data into a script, but I've got no idea how to iterate through the table from a script. Any pointers/ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are on the right track with the application route either with C or Python or whatever you feel convenient. Here is a different method that can be scripted.

**Export data from Excel as CSV**

```
$ cat test.csv 
Jacob Jacobs,M 
Rogers Bogers,M
Marsha Darsha,F
Tina Fina,F    
Mono Bono,M
```

**Import this into sqlite**

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import test.csv proxy
sqlite> select * from proxy2;
"Jacob Jacobs",M             
"Rogers Bogers",M            
"Marsha Darsha",F            
"Tina Fina",F                
"Mono Bono",M
```

**Remember count of males and females**

Let's say your table was called `main` in which you have real names, and you want to change them to names from `proxy` table randomly.

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE proxy (fullname text, gender text);
CREATE TABLE main(fullname TEXT,gender TEXT,age INT);

sqlite> select * from main;
fullname,gender,age
"John Smith",M,20
"Marshall Dubin",M,20
"Kate Ortiz",F,20
"Ron Bunsh",M,20
"Kelly Torro",F,20

sqlite> select count(*) from main where gender='M';
count(*)                                           
3                                                  
sqlite> select count(*) from main where gender='F';
count(*)                                           
2
```

Have your application remember this information that there are 3 Males and 2 Females.

**Execute update statement repeatedly with different offset**

```
sqlite> update main
   ...> set fullname = (
   ...>   select fullname from proxy where gender='M' order by random() limit 1)
   ...> where rowid = (
   ...>   select rowid from main where gender='M' order by rowid limit 0,1);
```

Change the `limit 0,1` to `limit 1,1` and re-execute. Go on till you reach `limit 2,1`. Since you have 3 records for Males, go from limit 0,1 to limit 2,1.

Repeat the same thing to anonymize Female records. Change `gender='M'` to `gender='F'`. Since there are only 2 females, you will execute `update` two times. Once with `limit 0,1` and then with `limit 1,1`.

If you run this in a transaction, my hope that your script should be able to churn through the updates quite fast.

**End Result**

WAS

```
fullname    gender      age       
----------  ----------  ----------
John Smith  M           20        
Marshall D  M           20        
Kate Ortiz  F           20        
Ron Bunsh   M           20        
Kelly Torr  F           20
```

IS

```
fullname       gender      age       
-------------  ----------  ----------
Rogers Bogers  M           20        
Jacob Jacobs   M           20        
Tina Fina      F           20        
Jacob Jacobs   M           20        
Jasmine        F           20
```

Example of scripting SQLite with Bash - http://andreaolivato.tumblr.com/post/133473114/using-sqlite3-in-bash
**Other option**

- In your application, hold the fake names in two arrays - one for male and one for female. The idea is to be able to pull a random fake name by gender on demand
- Do a `select rowid, gender from main order by rowid`
- Iterate through the records
- If gender is male, pull a random fake record from male array; likewise for female record
- Run `update main set fullname=<fake-record> where rowid=<selected-row-id>`